# Convert from console to windows service error

Tags: c#, powershell, windows-services, lync

in my solution i have a console project `reg` to start my app and it works fine

now i want to Replace console to a windows service `Service1`
but it doesn't  work and give me an error to connect with database

this is my solution and i use `Service1 item` instead Console `reg`

[image]

and this is my `onStart` Method

```
      protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
      {
            System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
                 EventLog.WriteEntry("Service Started...");
                 ConfigureServer();
      }
```

Here, the problem occurs  **cannot run database xds requested by the login**

```
 using (System.Management.Automation.PowerShell powershell = System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Create())
                     {
                          powershell.Runspace = myRunSpace;
                          powershell.Commands.AddScript("Get-CsTrustedApplicationPool");
                          Collection<PSObject> results = null;
                          Collection<ErrorRecord> errors = null;
                          try
                          {
                                results = powershell.Invoke();
                                errors = powershell.Streams.Error.ReadAll();
                          }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On which account your service is running?

[image]